# HTML table with rowspan and bgcolor

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table with rowspan same like in the html code:

```
<table class="" id="mergeTbl" border='1'>
<tbody>
  <tr >
      <td align="center" style="width:100px">A</td>
      <td align="center" style="width:100px">1</td>
      <td align="center" style="width:100px">12.01 Ct</td>
      <td align="center" style="width:100px">3.01</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="3">B</td>
        <td align="center">3</td>
        <td align="center">13.02 Ct</td>
        <td align="center">4.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">4</td>
        <td align="center" rowspan="2">11.48 Ct</td>
        <td align="center">2.70</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td align="center">1.70</td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="3">C</td>
        <td align="center">5</td>
        <td align="center">16.75 Ct</td>
        <td align="center">5.35</td></tr><tr>
        <td align="center">6</td>
        <td align="center">14.09 Ct</td>
        <td align="center">5.01</td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center">7</td>
        <td align="center">11.35 Ct</td>
        <td align="center">4.01</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Output:

[image]

I want to color with alternate row background color. Like:

[image]

Each row is in a loop such as A,B and C (Main Loop).

Comment: and where do you get stuck at?

Comment: hi can u change your table structure

Answer (score 0):

**Add This CSS**

```
<style>
    .style1{
        background-color: cyan;
    }
    .style2{
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML :**

```
echo "<table>";
    $select = "select * from table";
    $query = mysql_query($select)
    $i=0;
    while($i < mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($i%2==0){
        echo "<tr class='style1'>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<tr class='style2'>";
        }
        echo "<td>A</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```